# How can I get a border to switch colors indefinitely?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the border below that text, kind of pulse with lighter and darker greys automatically while the user is on the page. I tried using webkit animations in my CSS, but I don't have much experience with that, and it doesn't seem to be working. Here's my code:

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var exceptions = ["Bulls", "rhymes,", "spin", "blinding", "pinched", "oxygen", "tendrils", "exact", "agreement", "combination", "swallow", "smiles",
    "mirror", "treehouse", "project", "dwindling", "laughing", "fall", "stupor", "breaking", "skin", "untimely"
  ];

  $("p").each(function() { //for all paragraphs

    var txt = $(this).text() //get text, split it up, add spans where necessary, put it back together
      .split(" ")
      .map(function(x) {
        return exceptions.includes(x.toLowerCase()) ? x : "<span class='hover'>" + x + "</span>"
      }).join(" ");
    $(this).html(txt); //set the text to our newly manipulated text

  }).on("mouseover", ".hover", function() {

    $(this).addClass("hovering"); //set opacity to 100%

  }).on("mouseout", ".hovering", function() {
    $(this).attr("class", ""); //set opacity to 0%, remove "hover" events

  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 3%;
  height: 3% opacity: 0.5;
}

.hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hovering {
  opacity: 1;
}

span {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

p {
  cursor: default;
  line-height: 200%;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
}

@-webkit-keyframes p {
  0% {
    border-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: green;
  }
}

.story {
  -webkit-animation: p 10s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="arrow.png">

<br>

<div class=s tory>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3oshp7v0/#&togetherjs=5SSB2yJSF6

Comment: Make a fiddle/plunkr/pen, please.

Comment: You have an error here `<div class=s tory>`. It should be `<div class="story">`.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Ok I added a fiddle. Don't worry about most of it. The border is the primary problem.

Comment: Nice.  You've got some working answers here... you should probably accept one of them. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `border` set on the CSS rule `.style`. Animations only apply on the properties of the element they are on. You have to set the animation on the `p` elements (that actually have the border), or add a border to the `.story` element.

```css
p { /* p is the element that have the border, .story doesn't have it */
  cursor: default;
  line-height: 200%;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
}

@-webkit-keyframes p {
  0% { border-color: red; }
  50% { border-color: blue; }
  100% { border-color: green; }
}

p { /* set the animation on p which is the element that have the border */
  -webkit-animation: p 10s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="story">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your fiddle to make it blink infinitely.
https://jsfiddle.net/3oshp7v0/3/
I have changed your code as:

```
    img {
  width: 3%;
  height: 3% opacity: 0.5;
}

.hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hovering {
  opacity: 1;
}

span {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

p {
  cursor: default;
  line-height: 200%;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
}

.blink_me p{
    -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    -moz-animation-name: blinker;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    animation-name: blinker;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; border-color:red;}
    50% { opacity: 0.0; border-color:blue;}
    100% { opacity: 1.0; border-color:green;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; border-color:red;}
    50% { opacity: 0.0; border-color:blue;}
    100% { opacity: 1.0; border-color:green;}
}

@keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; border:red}
    50% { opacity: 0.0; border-color:blue}
    100% { opacity: 1.0; border-color:green}
}
```

The class blink_me p can be applied instead to hovering and you will have blink only on mouseover.

Please see.Also note that for animations to work properly across cross-browsers you have to define browser specific css. The provided one doesnot work with internet explorer. For that you will have to write that in javascript.

https://www.kapadiya.net/snippets/how-to-make-blinking-flashing-text-with-css3-and-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

It's a typical css-hack. Try Pseudo-elements:

```css
p{
    position: relative;
}
p:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    animation: bdColor 1s ease-out infinite alternate; 
}
@keyframes bdColor{ 
    0% { background-color: red; }
    50% { background-color: blue; }
    100% { background-color: green; } 
}
```